# how to match two curves in matplotlib whose data points are different and how to get the matched data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, curve-fitting, curve

i have this code which produce two graphs but what i need is this two curves needs to be matched and i want the matched data how i can do it the graph is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzJE9.png)

```
import numpy as np

#polynomial fit with degree = 2

#add fitted polynomial line to scatterplot
polyline = np.linspace(0, 280,1000 )
plt.ylim(0,1400)
plt.xlim(0,300)
#polynomial fit with degree = 2
model1 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 7))
model = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x1, y1, 13))
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.scatter(x1, y1)
plt.plot(polyline, model1(polyline))
plt.plot(polyline, model(polyline))

plt.show()
```

Comment: What is your expected output / final result?

Comment: The two curves should be matched and I want the matched data